# GDS Implementation (Sabre,Amadeus,worlspan)

Tags: .net, rest, asp.net-web-api

We want to develop a system which will communicate to various GDS's (Sabre,Amadeus,worlspan) for the Car rentals.which will push/ pull the data from GDS, we don't have any documents as such right now , So if any one knows how to proceed or any developer guide will be there please share the idea or links.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For Amadeus, I suggest to reach "Contact us" section on https://developers.amadeus.com/ or https://sandbox.amadeus.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ypu must contact your regional office of Amadeus GDS, Sabre GDS and Traveport/Worldspan and request access to developer enviroment.

- https://developer.sabre.com/home
- https://developers.amadeus.com/
- https://developer.travelport.com/web/developer/home